# Finding a line that contain a string using contains method

Tags: java

I have two files:

One is a CSV file that contains the following:

```
Class
weka.core.Memory
com.google.common.base.Objects
client.network.ForwardingObserver
```

Second is a txt file that contains the following:

```
1_tullibee  com.ib.client.ExecutionFilter
107_weka    weka.core.Memory
101_netweaver   com.sap.managementconsole.soap.axis.sapcontrol.HeapInfo
107_weka    weka.classifiers.Evaluation
guava   com.google.common.base.Objects
57_hft-bomberman    client.network.ForwardingObserver
18_jsecurity    org.jsecurity.web.DefaultWebSecurityManager
```

I would like to retrieve the lines in the txt files that contain the classes in the CSV file. To do so:

```java
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/nasser/Desktop/Link to Software Testing/Experiments/running_scripts/exp_23/run3/CSV/MissingClasses_RW_No_Reduction.csv"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("==>> " + line);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/home/nasser/Desktop/Link to Software Testing/Experiments/running_scripts/exp_23/selection (copy).txt"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();

            if(currentLine.contains("**>> " + line)){
                System.out.println(currentLine);
            }else {
                System.out.println("not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get `not found` with all the classes in the CSV which is not the case I expect. I expect the following lines to be printed:

```
107_weka    weka.core.Memory
guava   com.google.common.base.Objects
57_hft-bomberman    client.network.ForwardingObserver
```

How to solve that?

Comment: `currentLine.contains("**>> " + line)` None of the text contains `**>>` so nothing is found.

Comment: I removed it and still not working

Comment: this is where debugging comes in handy ;)

Comment: before the line `if(currentLine.contains(line)){` add the following line: `System.out.println("Testing if **"+currentLine+"** contains **"+line+"**);` you will find out what the problem is. the 2 stars will help you find if there are exrta spaces where you don't expect.

Comment: @StephaneM `Testing if **107_weka weka.core.Memory** contains **"weka.core.Memory"**`. It actually contains it !!

Comment: have you debugged? you can mimic debugging, by adding a print statement outside of the if statement to print currentLine and line

Comment: Works for me. The fix that is mentioned in first comment, I didn't see it in the question, but you probably forgot to recompile after :)

Comment: and are you sure that your **csv** is not a Comma Separated Values file, that is, the values are separated by `,`? And there are no empty spaces, tabs at the end of the lines? And don;t forget to close the Scanner at the end of the loop....

Comment: But why your log output `"weka.core.Memory"`.  It seems you have quotes in your search text. This would explain why the text is not found.

Comment: maybe the question is to have `not found` output only once per value from the *CSV* file and only if it is not found at all in the entire *TXT* file? Actually, the desired output just has no `not found` - so just delete that output and the `else` block

Comment: @AdamAmin read carefully: `**107_weka weka.core.Memory**` DOES NOT contain `**"weka.core.Memory"**` There are extra double quotes!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the `not found` and the `==>> *` output, just delete the corresponding lines of code

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("csv.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("copy.txt"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();

            if (currentLine.contains(line)) {
                System.out.println(currentLine);
            }
        }

        scanner.close();  // added this, could use try-with but that is *advanced*
    }
}
```

this will generate the following output, exactly as requested:

> ```
> 107_weka    weka.core.Memory
> guava   com.google.common.base.Objects
> 57_hft-bomberman    client.network.ForwardingObserver
> ```

<sup>obviously used files located in my folder...</sup>

Comment: He is already using try-with for the buffered reader, so why not add it for the scanner as well. not sure what you want to express with `advanced`.

Comment: @second and what about the second file, the one opened with the `Scanner`? It will not be closed together with the `BufferedReader` just because it is inside the same block - maybe a bit `advanced`?? [:-)

Comment: I was more thinking along the line, that you might want to add another try with for the scanner. As he uses it to close the BufferedReader, he should be aware how it is working. So wrapping another try with around the Scanner should not be that `advanced`. Obviously they wont be closed together, even if that were the case, the second file is opened multiple times (in the buffers try with block).

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents: If you're using Java 8, and the CSV file is relatively small, you can simply do this:

```java
List<String> csvLines = Files.lines(Paths.get(csvFilename))).collect(Collectors.toList());
Files.lines(Paths.get(txtFileName)))
 .filter(txtLine -> csvLines.stream().anyMatch(txtLine::contains))
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```